# Creating Shapes in visio using c#

Tags: c#, visio, bpmn, visio2013

Hi i need to develop an addin for creating diagram objects in visio.I am able to create the top shape but not its derived types . **for EG** i am able to creat Start event in visio using c#, but couldn't create Start Event of message type or others
[image]

In the above picture i have 3 start event , well the BPMN Start Event was added and its property **Trigger/Result** option was changed

> Start Event - Multiple
>
> Start Event - Message
>
> Start Event - None

but all the above 3 shapes are from Start Event. How to create the Message start event or Multiple start evet etc.

I am creating shapes in visio using

```
            Visio.Master shapetodrop = Masters.get_ItemU(@"Start Event");
            Visio.Shape DropShape = ActivePage.Drop(shapetodrop, x, y);
            DropShape.Name = name;
            DropShape.Text = name;
```

but this only creates Start Event , how to create Message Start EVent , Multiple Start Event etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iteration through each property of a shape in visio

```
  short iRow = (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowFirst;
            while (shape.get_CellsSRCExists((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp, iRow, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue, (short)Visio.VisExistsFlags.visExistsAnywhere) != 0)
            {
                Visio.Cell c = shape.get_CellsSRC((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp, iRow, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue);
                         switch (c.Name)
                        {
                            case "Prop.BpmnTriggerOrResult":
                                shape.Cells[c.Name].FormulaU = "\"" + "Message" + "\"";
                                break;

                        }
}
```

and i can get Message start event. Like this value for all the property of a shape can be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you the answer in VBA, and expect that you can convert to C#?

Microsoft in their wisdom created quite complex shapes for BPMN, so, once you have set the EventType, the list for the possible TriggerOrResult is updated...

```
Public Sub DropEventShape()
On Error GoTo errHandler

'EventType is one of the following : "Start;Start (Non-Interrupting);Intermediate;Intermediate (Non-Interrupting);Intermediate (Throwing);End"

Const mstName As String = "Start Event"
Const eventType As String = "Start"
Const triggerOrResult As String = "Multiple"

Dim doc As Visio.Document
Dim stn As Visio.Document
Dim mst As Visio.Master

    For Each doc In Application.Documents
        If doc.Title = "BPMN Shapes" Then
            Set stn = doc
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If stn Is Nothing Then
        GoTo exitHere
    End If

    Set mst = stn.Masters(mstName)

Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double
    x = Application.ActivePage.PageSheet.Cells("PageWidth").ResultIU * 0.5
    y = Application.ActivePage.PageSheet.Cells("PageHeight").ResultIU * 0.5

    Set shp = Application.ActivePage.Drop(mst, x, y)

Dim iEventType As Integer
Dim aryEventTypes() As String

    aryEventTypes = Split(shp.Cells("Prop.BPMNEventType.Format").ResultStr(""), ";")
    For iEventType = 0 To UBound(aryEventTypes)
        If aryEventTypes(iEventType) = eventType Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    shp.Cells("Prop.BPMNEventType").Formula = "=INDEX(" & iEventType & ",Prop.BPMNEventType.Format)"

Dim iTriggerOrResult As Integer
Dim aryTriggerOrResults() As String
    aryTriggerOrResults = Split(shp.Cells("Prop.BpmnTriggerOrResult.Format").ResultStr(""), ";")
    For iTriggerOrResult = 0 To UBound(aryTriggerOrResults)
        If aryTriggerOrResults(iTriggerOrResult) = triggerOrResult Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    shp.Cells("Prop.BpmnTriggerOrResult").Formula = "=INDEX(" & iTriggerOrResult & ",Prop.BpmnTriggerOrResult.Format)"

exitHere:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume exitHere
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) :)